# How to Resolve this issue web site under price and description tab shown this parameter error?

Tags: php, parameters, warnings

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in /var/www/eu-biler.dk/public_html/wp-includes/post-template.php on line 319

// If the requested page doesn't exist.

```
if ( $elements['page'] > count( $elements['pages'] ) ) {

    // Give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist.

    $elements['page'] = count( $elements['pages'] );
}
```

[This one screen shot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kePvB.png)

Comment: `$elements['pages']` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to array before using count:

```
var cnt = count( (array) $elements['pages'] );
if ( $elements['page'] > cnt ) {
    // Give them the highest numbered page that DOES exist.
    $elements['page'] = cnt;
}
```

Comment: Error Gone Hide but Tabs not active there

Comment: can you `var_dump($elements['pages']);` to see what contains?